# Sum of two consecutive index equals to target. Throwing up error when taking target equals index [0] , [1]

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
target = 3

for i in range (0,len(list)-1):

    if (list[i]+list[i+1]== target):
        print (list.index(list[i], list[i-1], list[i+1]));
        print (list.index(list[i+1], list[i-1], list[i+1]));

else : print ("NO SUCCESS");
```

## Error while running:

```
print (list.index(list[i], list[i-1], list[i+1]));
```

ValueError: 1 is not in list

Answer (score 1):

Not the downvoter, but check out the [documentation for index()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), and pay attention to what exactly you're asking index() for, when you call it like you do above. (Note that the last two parameters are optional.)

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do though; if you'd like help, you'll need to add more details and explain what your goal is, what you've tried, and/or why/how you think it should work.